# Click events not firing after Foundation reveal close

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-reveal

I have a page with a button which when clicked opens a reveal modal using jquery and foundation. It looks a little like:

```
$(".playersScores").unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
    $('#addScore2').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    //Do some stuff
});
```

In the modal there is a submit button which when clicked closes the reveal like:

```
$(".submitButton").unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
    // do some stuff
    $('#addScore2').foundation('reveal', 'close');
});
```

This all works once the modal closes the player scores button no longer works until the page is reloaded - it just stops listening for events.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: why are you using .unbind('click') ?

Comment: it's a hangover from when the project was using jquery mobile - I'm in the process of re-writing it. I still see the same problem if I just use .bind('click') on. click or any other variation.

Comment: Having play a bit more last the issue seems to be that after closing the reveal I'm calling a function which removes and re-adds a whole bunch of elements to the DOM - including the playersscores div.

I've tried adding $(document).foundation(); in this function call but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had asked this question on the foundation forums:

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/17739-click-events-not-firing-after-foundation-reveal-close

the solution I ended up with was:

```
$(document).on('click', ".playersScores", function () {
    $('#addScore2').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    //Do some stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.off().on()` instead of `unbind().bind()` so that your new content -- including the new `div.playersscores` -- picks up the event handlers correctly.